# Javascript inheritance: push of undefined

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

```
testA = function(){
this._data = [];
}

testA.prototype.add = function(data){
this._data.push(data) // Here i am facing this._data is undefined
}


testB = function(){}
testB.prototype = Object.create(testA);
var instance = new testB;

testB.prototype.pushData = function(data){
instance.prototype.add(data); 
}

function (data){
  instance.prototype.add(data); 
}
instance.pushData("someData")
```

In the above javascript snippet, i am facing 'Cannot read property 'push' of undefined' error

Is my inheritance concepts is wrong? can any one help to resolve this inheritance issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several mistakes/inaccuracies in your code:

1. It is cleaner to write like this to preserve prototypal inheritance

   ```
   testB.prototype = Object.create(testA.prototype);
   ```
2. to make the `instance` object have `_data` property you have to call
   first the `testA` (parent) in the `testB`.

   ```
   testB = function() { testA.call(this); }
   ```
3. I don't know what you meant but this function looks weird:

   ```
   function (data){ instance.prototype.add(data); }
   ```
4. Inside `testB` you can use `this` to make reference to parent's (`testA`'s) properties in order to call `add()` function: `this.add(data);` This function will be first searched in `testB`'s properties and then through `testB`'s `__proto__` reference in `testA` prototype object (see point #1 above).

In the end it all might look like this:

```js
testA = function() {
    this._data = [];
}
testA.prototype.add = function(data){
    this._data.push(data);
    //console.log(this._data);
}

testB = function() {
    testA.call(this);
}
testB.prototype = Object.create(testA.prototype);
testB.prototype.pushData = function(data){
    this.add(data); 
}
var instance = new testB();
instance.pushData("someData");
console.log(instance._data);
```

**UPDATE**

```js
testA = function() {
    this._data = [];
}
testA.prototype.add = function(data){
    var data = data + ' from parent testA';
    this._data.push(data);
}

testB = function() {
    testA.call(this);
}
testB.prototype = Object.create(testA.prototype);
testB.prototype.add = function(data){
    testA.prototype.add.call(this, data); // call to parent's add(); data is passed to the parent's add() function too.
// now you can do some actions intended for testB like:
    var data = data + ' from child testB';
    this._data.push(data);
}
var instance = new testB();
instance.add("someData");
console.log(instance._data);
```

Also you can do like this:

```
var a = new testA(); 
a.add(); // add() in testA prototyp is called
var b = new testB(); 
b.add(); // add() in testB prototyp is called
```

Without creating an instance of testA you can call its add() method from any place only like this:

```
testA.prototype.add.call(context, data);
```

to summarize, there are 3 options (in fact 2): create instance of testA and call its add(), call testA's add() from testB's add() and call testA's add() wherever you want using call()/apply().

There are some really smart OOP patterns out there that allow you to have references in one object to another one and do some fancy calls. But it is a vast topic (OOP) and is beyond the scope of this question I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for your response

Comment: you are welcome! fell free to upvote or mark as answer answers that have been useful :)

Comment: Hi curveball one clarification supposes if the testB also having the same method like `add` now I want to execute both same methods from the parent and child so in this case what I need to do?

Comment: In this example i need to call add method from both testA and testB `testA = function() {
    this._data = [];
}
testA.prototype.add = function(data){
 console.info("testA mehod")
    this._data.push(data);
    //console.log(this._data);
}

testB = function() {
    testA.call(this);
}
testB.prototype = Object.create(testA.prototype);
testB.prototype.pushData = function(data){
    this.add(data); 
}
testB.prototype.add = function(){
 console.info("testB method")
}

var instance = new testB();
instance.pushData("someData");
console.log(instance._data);`

Comment: Generally, in such cases you need to call child's add() and in child's add() you have to call parent's add() as I did for constructor. Check the updated answer. Also if you want both methods to be totally independent and be called from different contexts, just call each of them from their respective object: if you need add() from testA, create a new testA object and call its add(). The same goes for testB.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @vurveball Now it's clear and I was in bit confusion with java and javascript.

Comment: yeah, the JS native inheritance implementation is based on prototypes and differs from one in most "big" languages like Java. Although the ideas remain the same - you can override parent's method; call it from the child object, set it to be private and stuff.

Comment: Oh cool .. Thanks for the example which you gave and sorry I dont have option to give upvote or-else I could give:-(

Comment: ohh...you are welcome! Don't worry. You can choose it as answer. Right below 0 score of this answer you can find a check mark (it becomes green if you click on it).